# Which mobile racing game featuring a red-roof car is this?

Tags: game-identification

[image]

This is a screenshot has taken from a [YouTube mobile review video](https://youtu.be/XaDU2xJT9pg?t=214) where reviewer is playing a game.
Graphics of this game looks interesting. What is the name of the game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It's CarX Rally

The exact location of the OP's screenshot:

[image]
<sup>Source: [this YouTube review](https://youtu.be/VVwPRFj8Kjg?t=250)</sup>

[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carxtech.rally) is the Google Play page for it. And here's another screenshot, for your viewing pleasure:

[image]

Comment: Is it really? The UI looks almost entirely different.

Comment: @nick012000 How so? There are differences, yes, but the overall design and placements are the same, and I think icons like vehicle damage and button assignment could easily be dependent on the stage (of the race) or game mode (or perhaps the game or even Android version).

Comment: @nick012000 Also: see update :)